# Case statement in where clause with "not equal" condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is just a very simple version of my actual query and I'd like to know how I can write just one query instead of two for the following select?

```
 If @ShowZero = 0 
     Select Value From Metrics 
 Else
     Select Value From Metrics Where Value <> 0
```

I have tried something as

```
  Select Value From Metrics Where Value = Case @ShowZero = 0 then Value Else (here I'm stuck).
```

@ShowZero is a flag of 0 and 1.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `case` for this:

```
Select Value
From Metrics 
Where @ShowZero = 0 or Value <> 0;
```

EDIT:

This works, because, uhh, that is how boolean logic works.  In other words, if you did a logic table for your expression, it would look like:

```
@ShowZero    Value       Action
   0           0         Show row
   0         other       Show row
 other         0         Filter out row
 other       other       Show row
```

There are multiple ways to express this.  The `if` statement is one of them.  You could say:  "I'm going to show a row unless @ShowZero is not 0 *and* value is `0`".  The `where` clause would be:

```
where not (@ShowZero <> 0 and Value = 0)
```

Alternatively, you could say:  "I'm going to show a row when either of the following is true:

- `@ShowZero = 0`
- `Value <> 0`

If both are true great!  I'll still show the row."  This is the `where` clause that I used.

Comment: While reading more about boolean logic in SQL, I found this article: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx. It's helpful for me, so I thought I would share it in case it may be help to somebody else.